# Values of a and b in a power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition, solution-verification

The question that I am trying to answer is the following:

*Two sets A and B contains a and b elements respectively. If power set of A contains 8 more elements than that of B, value of ‘b’ and ‘a’ are respectively

a) 3, 4

b) 5, 6

c) 1, 2

d) None of the mentioned*

I assumed that by 'value', the size or cardinality is meant. And so, I just simply used 2^n.

By plugging in 3 and 4, I got 8 and 16 respectively. Since the question mentions that A has eight more elements, then I supposed that my answer, letter A, satisfies that because the difference of 16 and 8 is 8.

Is my assumption correct, or did I do something along the way?

Comment: It looks like you chose the correct answer.  The question indicates that $a$ is the cardinality of $A$, and $b$ of $B$.  If $2^a-2^b=8,$ then $2^{b}(2^{a-b}-1)=8$, so $b=3$ and $a-b=1$

Comment: Yes thats the right way to approach this.

Comment: I'm not crazy about the wording "A and B contains a and b elements respectively"  The first three times I read it I interpreted it (incorectly) as $a\in A$ and $b \in B$ and the question made no sense.  But the fourth reading I realized they meant $a$ and $b$ where numbers and are the *number* of elements each set has.i.e. $|A|=a$ and $|B|=b$. I reread it and see that of course that is what they meant. But there is something about the wording that seemed very unnatural... In the end though you must solve $2^a-2^b=8$.  So, yes, your interpretation is correct.

Comment: *NOT* a good question if you are in the slightest bit dyslexic or english isn't your first question.

Comment: The title does not reflect the fact that the question deals with cardinalities , and wrongly suggests it deals with some elements of a given set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it right.

A set with $n$ elements has a power set of cardinality $2^n$.